# Installing packages in R using minicran

Tags: r, cran

I am a corporate user of R with firewall constraints. I downloaded miniCRAN in another laptop and transferred the local repository to my laptop. Now I am running the following code

```
> install.packages("dplyr", repos = "C:/Users/1030780/Documents/R/packages_Mrunal" , type = c("win.binary"), dependencies = TRUE)
```

I get the following error:

```
>  Warning in install.packages :
>       unable to access index for repository http://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib:
>       cannot open URL 'http://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
>     Installing package into ‘C:/Users/1030780/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
>     (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       unable to access index for repository C:/Users/1030780/Documents/R packages_Mrunal/bin/windows/contrib/4.2:
>       cannot open URL 'C:/Users/1030780/Documents/R packages_Mrunal/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       package ‘dplyr’ is not available as a binary package for this version of R
>     
>     A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
>     see the ideas at
>     https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Comment: It's odd that the error message `cannot open URL 'C:/Users/1030780/Documents/R packages_Mrunal/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'` seems to be missing a slash compared to the path you used in the `repos=` parameter. Is this a copy/paste error or is the slash really missing? Does the file `C:/Users/1030780/Documents/R packages_Mrunal/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES` exist? How did you initialize your miniCRAN repo? Did you you call `makeRepo`? What arguments did you pass?

Comment: Yes, I did do a MakeRepo and now I have my miniCRAN repository in place.I also tried the following:                              
      install.packages("dplyr", repos = "file://C:/Users/1030780/Documents/R packages_Mrunal/MiniCran_Mrunal" 
                               , type = c("win.binary"), dependencies = TRUE). Here is log:
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file '//C:/Users/1030780/Documents/R packages_Mrunal/MiniCran_Mrunal/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection